# Transfer function of boost converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

When I have gone through some books I have found the expression of the DC Gain of the the boost converter in current mode is given by

```
H0=(RL/Ri)*1/(2*M+(RL*Tsw)/(L*M^2)*(1/2+Sa/Sn))
```

But I did not find out what is the expression of the M, please can you give me the expression of this M and from where does it come??

Here is attached the final expression given by [OnSemiconductor](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Boost%20CCM%20DCM%20CM.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Verbal Kint makes most sense.

If you multiply the DC gain on slide 35 by \$ \frac{R_L}{R_L} \$

$$H_0 = \frac{k_0-k_i}{g_f - (g_0+g_i) - g_r - \frac{1}{R_L} } \frac{R_L}{R_L} $$ 
and substitute the equations given in slide 27 into the term \$k_0-k_i\$,

then \$H_0\$ evaluates to

$$H_0 = R_L \frac{\frac{1-D}{R_i}}{g_f R_L - (g_0+g_i) R_L - g_r R_L - 1 } = \frac{R_L}{R_i} \frac{1-D}{g_f R_L - (g_0+g_i) R_L - g_r R_L - 1 } $$

Using \$M=\frac{1}{1-D}\$ it looks more and more to the DC gain \$H_0\$ given on slide 50:

$$H_0 = \frac{R_L}{R_i} \frac{1}{M (g_f R_L - (g_0+g_i) R_L - g_r R_L - 1) } $$

Answer (score 2):

In the technical literature, the parameter \$M\$ refers to the dc transfer function of the considered converter: \$M=\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$. For a boost converter operated in the continuous conduction mode or CCM, it can be shown that \$M=\frac{1}{1-D}\$ with \$D\$ the duty ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell without a circuit but typically M represents the mutual inductance between transformer winding's, so if the circuit has a transformer in it:

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance

[image]

Comment: When substituting s=0, it is easily to see **M has to be dimensionless**. So, in this case, it cannot be mutual inductance.